# Get unmatched string while using re.finditer

Tags: python, regex

My simple config file consists of parameters grouped into block. Something like this:

```
param1: 1,2,3
param2: foo

param1: 4,5,6
param2: another_foo
```

I wrote in Python a regexp and used the `re.finditer` method to iterate over these blocks of parameters to parse then and add to the DB.

The problem is that if the block is incorrect thus does not match my regexp it's being silently skipped.

What I want is to detect such bad block and notify user that he has an error somewhere in a block x.

Should I necessarily use the `match()` method before iterating over blocks with`finditer` or there is a more comprehensive solution?

Comment: Please show your code and what a bad block looks like.

Comment: Maybe do it in two steps.  Write a pattern that will match a block: line(s) of text followed by a blank line.  Then use ```re.finditer``` to feed blocks to another regex that can parse AND validate a block.

Comment: @wwii yes, right now I do `splitlines()` and then iterate over them and run `match()` but I thought there is a way to extract unmatched pieces after `finditer` did it's job.

Comment: Like @HappyLeapSecond said.

Answer (score 0):

I think that finditer is not a good match for what you're trying to do as it will return only matches skipping anything in between. If I'm understanding correctly I think you should split on the empty lines and then iterate the blocks running `re.match` and reporting appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but if anyone is still interested in how to use `re.finditer` with crude error detection, check [this link](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/ffbd2fde8d44b93c22f0) with a good example of how to use named groups as named tokens and my answer about how I implemented the simple error detection using that same example.